# How to get container ID by golang

Tags: docker, go

I use golang to develop application . I want get container  in application.I hava tired by shell.But I want to get container by go. thanks

Comment: What are you trying to build?  What have you done so far?  (For ordinary use and just talking to an existing container, you don't actually need the container ID; if your process could access the container ID it would have unrestricted access over the host.)

Comment: I assume English is not your first language (neither is mine) and might be a bit hard to fully express the problem you have at hand, but try to elaborate your question a bit more. It's hard to understand what you're actually trying to do by the way your question is phrased. Help us understand what you're trying achieve and you sure will get the help you need.

Comment: There are examples in here with extra details https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/

Comment: Another example can be found in this question [Programmatically check if Docker container process ended with non-zero status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849954/programmatically-check-if-docker-container-process-ended-with-non-zero-status)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use docker/client
https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client

Example code:

```
# listcontainers.go

package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/docker/docker/api/types"
    "github.com/docker/docker/client"
)

func main() {
    cli, err := client.NewClientWithOpts(client.FromEnv)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    containers, err := cli.ContainerList(context.Background(), types.ContainerListOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, container := range containers {
        fmt.Printf("%s %s\n", container.ID[:10], container.Image)
    }
}
```

Then execute it like this

```
DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.35 go run listcontainers.go
```

More about docker engine SDKs and API
https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/

Comment: link only answers are in general frowned upon on stack overflow, could you give a small code example.